# Expand jQuery -> Navigation sub-menu -> sub-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, navigation

as a jQuery Noob I need some help with a jQuery script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$(".sub-menu").hide();
$(".current_page_item .sub-menu").slideDown(200);;
$("li.menu-item").click(function () { 
    if ($('.sub-menu', this).length >=1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    $(".sub-menu").slideUp(200);; 
    $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideDown(200);;
    event.stopPropagation();
});
});
```

This script already works great. Now I want to expand it to the third level. E.g.

Page 1
------> Page 1 Second Level
-----------> Page 1 Third Level.

Right now the second and third level me if I click on the First level menu, but the third level should only be shown if the Second Level Page 1 is clicked.

Anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance
Thorsten

---

EDIT
Anyone an idea why the script doesn't work on Firefox?

Firebug reports after click:
ReferenceError: event is not defined nav.js:7:5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".current_page_item").children(".sub-menu").slideDown(200);
  $("li.menu-item").click(function() {
    $(this).parent('ul').find(".sub-menu").slideUp(200);
    if ($('.sub-menu', this).length >=1) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").slideDown(200);
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

As an example can play here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhydzxt8/1/)

p.s. take a note then in fiddle a didn't add class "menu-item" to li elements